# Nginx location versioning decimal

Tags: nginx

I have an Nginx location block setup that allows me to provide versioning for my static files so that I can allow the user to cache the files and when I update the website, the version takes place and still pulls the most up to date file.

My question is, how can I modify the location block to allow /cdn/v1.04/js as it only allows me to do /cdn/v1/js?

```
location ~ /cdn/v[0-9]+/(js|css|img|fonts)/(.*) {
    access_log off;
    expires max;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/$2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed the dot in your regex.

```
location ~ /cdn/v[0-9.]+/(js|css|img|fonts)/(.*) {
    access_log off;
    expires max;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/$2 =404;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up going with this result as it was flexible for the versioning section.

```
location ~ /cdn/(.*)/(js|css|img|fonts)/(.*) {
    access_log off;
    expires max;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$2/$3 =404;
}
```